# Use C++ library in C# with Bitmap type?

Tags: c#, c++, types, call, dllimport

Let me explain, I' ve found some informations how to make a DLL and call it from C# code, but what I want to do is to replace Bitmap.Save(String path) with custom-made C++ function

I want to optimize my code, because C# bitmap Save() method seems to have a tons of shitload Strings / Stringbuilders etc. which is making my code creepy in profiler data

How to write C++ function to work with Bitmap C# class? To pass the bitmap parameter...

Should I have rather write full C++ Dll for bitmap optimization rather than hardtrying to mix both languages?

Comment: Let me get this straight, you want to optimize a .NET Framework method? What exactly is your goal and why can't you achieve it in C#? If the only reason for C++ is that it looks less creepy in profiler data, why not write your program in C++?

Comment: I think that sometimes I will be forced to do something like that, so this case is a training tbh. I don't know how to optimize framework methods because I don't see the way to integrate deeper in code than just Bitmap.Save().

Comment: I don't think you are in a position to "optimize" the .NET Framework if you cannot figure out how to pass a bitmap to C++ from the documentation or Daniels answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the bitmap GDI+ handle using Bitmap.GetHbitmap()

Comment: Can you tell something more?